# Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'none'"

Tags: javascript, security, debugging, content-security-policy

I faced the issue that on my webpage sometimes I am getting the error from content security policy that ->

[Report Only] Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-lrDdfLLxqOJeQihCgTDZKkuSQiZSz5vqmq3u8IkuqSE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

when I have this error , I have this more than 300 times . but it's really hard to reproduce , can you suggest me the ways , what should be the reason? why it's throwing the error randomly?

Comment: The most likely cause is one of your dependencies injects inline javascript in the code when running, but that is (correctly) prevented by `script-src 'none'` as all javascript should be loaded from file, not inline in html (to prevent a form of XSS). When this happens, you should be able to investigate in the browser dev console which dependency this is coming from (finding this will probably be hard if your app is already bundled and minified).